# How to solve write after end error in nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js, blob

Im trying to download multiple files from an azure blob storage. I have a following code.

```
exports.fileDownload = (req,res,next) => {
   for(i=0;i<req.body.FileName.length;i++){
    downloadFileName1.push(req.body.FileName[i]);
    req.body.downloadFileName = downloadFileName1; 
    blobfilename1.push(req.body.Entity_ID + '/' + req.body.FileType + '/' + 
    req.body.FileName[i]);
    req.body.blobFileName = blobfilename1;
   }
     blobservice.getBlobDataToStream(req,res)
   }

------

const getBlobDataToStream = async function(req,res){
  for(var j=0;j<downloadNames.Length;j++){
     res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + downloadNames[j]);
     res.setHeader("Content-Type","image/jpg");
     res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Requested-With,content-type");
  }
  for(var k=0;k<blobF.Length;k++){
     getBlob(blobfilename[k]);
  }

function getBlob(blobFileNamee){
    blobService.getBlobToStream(storageName, blobFileNamee , res, function(error, result, response) 
   {
        console.log("------------------")
        if(error){
            console.log('error',error);
            res.send({error:error, status: false});
        }
        else{ 
            console.log('resp',result);
            resp = result; 
            res.end(); 

        }
     })
    } 
  }
```

Can anybody please help me with this? Im getting "write after end" error.

Comment: post the whole code, because that seems to be inside an express route. The error is clear though, but I'll give an answer once you submit the whole code, so there won't be misunderstandings.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Thank you. I have posted.. Could you Please Check?

Comment: Are you trying to download several files in the same request?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande yes..

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle it asynchronously. Wrap your callback into a promise and resolve or reject it.In the for loop where you are calling the function, make the function as await.

```
for(var k=0;k<blobF.Length;k++){
 await this.getBlob(blobfilename[k]);
}

static async getBlob(blobFileNamee){
 return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
 blobService.getBlobToStream(storageName, blobFileNamee , res, function(error,result, 
 response) 
{
    console.log("------------------")
    if(error){
        console.log('error',error);
        reject(error);
        res.send({error:error, status: false});
    }
    else{ 
        console.log('resp',result);
        resolve(result);
    }
 })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're ending the request in each `getBlob` which happens several times for each request. A request can only be ended **once**, that's why you're getting that error.

The other issue you have, is that you want to send multiple files in a single request, that won't work on browsers. So my recommendation is to zip all the files, and only send the zipped file instead.

You can use something like [zipstream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zipstream) & `blobService.createReadStream` instead of `getBlobToStream`